# Why is my OpenGL enabled Java game not detected by Fraps?

Tags: opengl, java, hardware-acceleration

Recently I found out that I could enable OpenGL hardware acceleration in my Java game with the line

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");
```

Initial tests showed a big boost in performance. However, several days later I wanted to make a small test video using [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) but I found out that it didn't recognize my application (as in the  FPS counter did not show and I could not record anything). After I removed the earlier mentioned line of code (thus disabling OpenGL hardware acceleration) it recorded just fine.

Is there any way to use Fraps while I have OpenGL enabled in my Java game?

Comment: You could grab the framebuffer/canvas as a texture and write it to disk each frame, then join the images into a movie using ffmpeg or something.